# Data validation for Excel percentage cell

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I'm building an excel spreadsheet and right now I'm calculating percentages of accomplishment.

I have a list, with a minimum of 1 item and a maximum of 5. To calculate the percentage according to the number of items in the list I'm using this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(J12:J16; TRUE)/COUNTA(B12:G16)
```

This returns the correct value, depending on how many items are in the list. However if the user checks a blank box, the percentage keeps going up. For example: If the list has 1 item, but the user checks the 5 boxes the percentage will be 500%.

I'm trying to insert data validation in the cell that has the formula. It already changes to red if the percentage goes above 100%, but I can't display an error message when the percentage goes above 100%. I've tried custom, whole numbers, decimals, pretty much all kinds of validations.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Data Validation does not work on cells with formulas or cells that are linked to controls (e.g. text boxes). See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/more-on-data-validation-f38dee73-9900-4ca6-9301-8a5f6e1f0c4c , where is states that "Data validation is designed to show messages and prevent invalid entries only when users type data directly in a cell."

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what you have done, so we might find a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

```
=MIN(COUNTIF(J12:J16; TRUE)/COUNTA(B12:G16),1)
```